# Free online quiz using PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently searching for a an free/open source for online quiz system using php.

Objectives:

1. Able to promote link to students for answering the quizzes
2. Able to report outcomes for all students and their answers/marks

Answer (score 0):

I have been using WP Pro Quiz plugin for Wordpress and it has served the purpose very well. It comes with lot of features too. Have a look at it here https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pro-quiz/

Edit: forgot to mention that its free and meets both of your requirements